# Descargar carpeta con SSH

Tags: aws, ssh, wget

Tengo acceso via consola SSH a una carpeta en un servicio AWS, ¿como puedo descargar toda una carpeta a mi PC local?

he probado con algo así como
~$ wget nombreDeArchivo

y no funciona ... loque hace es tratar de encontrar "http://nombreDeArchivo", es decir trata de buscarlo en la red global y el archivo o carpeta a descargar en este caso está localmente en el servidor

---

Ambas respuestas .. al final un amigo local me hizo notar que podía usar el mismo IDE que uso para desarrollar "PHP Storm" para configurar esta descarga y a partir de allí, - todo fue muy fácil ... Gracias a Marco lo primero que hice fue compactar toda la carpeta para facilitar tener todo en un sólo archivo y luego tomando la sugerencia de usar una conexión SFTP de Abraham Guerrero.
Gracias amigos !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te sugiero instales un cliente de ftp en tu computadora te recomiendo FileZilla pero al configurar tu conexion vas a selccionar el protocolo SFTP para poder utilizar SSH 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si lo haces desde una conexion rapida llena los datos y en puerto utiliza el 22

Answer (score 4):

### Con `scp`

Suponiendo que tu carpeta está en `/home/tu_usuario/carpeta1` en el equipo remoto.

1. Dentro de tu instancia, entra un nivel antes con `cd /home/tu_usuario/`
2. Crea un archivo `.tar.gz` de esa carpeta con `tar czf carpeta1.tar.gz carpeta1`
3. Sal de su sesión de `ssh` en esa instancia de EC2.
4. Copia el archivo `tar.gz` a tu equipo local con

   ```
   scp usuario_de_la_instancia@ip_de_instancia:/home/tu_usuario/carpeta1.tar.gz .
   ```

   Donde el punto "`.`" indica el directorio actual. Después de esto tendrás el archivo `carpeta1.tar.gz` en tu directorio actual.
5. Descomprime con `tar xf carpeta1.tar.gz`

Puedes hacerlo sin en archivo `tar` con el parámetro `-r`, si no te interesa la compresión, por ejemplo.

```
scp -r usuario_remoto@ip_de_instancia:/home/tu_usuario/carpeta1 .
```

### A través del "sftp"

Descarga algún cliente de sftp y configuralo con la ruta, ip, contraseña o llave privada de la instancia de EC2. Incluso editores como Atom o Sublime Text tienen paquetes que te permiten hacer uso de sftp para la transferencia de archivos.

### Con el cliente de `ssh`

Una forma rápida de hacerlo y en una línea es, en resumen, en el equipo remoto ir al nivel de la carpeta para luego comprimirla, enviar lo comprimido al *stdout* y ese *stdout* recibirlo en el equipo local con una descompresión. Todo en una sola línea.

Ejemplo.

Suponiendo que la carpeta que quieres se encuentra en `/tmp` y se llama `carpeta1`, puedes aplicar alguna de estas opciones.

```
ssh usuario_remoto@ip_de_instancia 'cd /tmp/; tar cz carpeta1' | tar xz  # Si deseas compresión
```

O

```
ssh usuario_remoto@ip_de_instancia 'cd /tmp/; tar c carpeta1' | tar x  # Si no te importa la compresión.
```

Y, dentro de la ruta donde hayas corrido ese comando encontrarás la carpeta llamada "carpeta1" descomprimida.

### Con `rsync`

```
rsync -avzh usuario_remoto@ip_de_instancia:/home/tu_usuario/carpeta1 .
```

Los parámetros `-v`, y `-h` son para hacer verboso el proceso, `-a` que es en modo archivo y `-z` indica que el archivo será comprimido durante la transferencia.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza -r para hacerlo recursivo. Por ejemplo:

```
scp -r usuario@host:/la/ruta/directorio /ruta/destino/local/
```

O en su caso si quieres que se copie dentro del directorio donde estas posicionado con ./

```
scp -r usuario@host:/la/ruta/directorio ./
```

Saludos!